# How to get rid of the minus in floating zero (-0.0)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I type:

```
a=float(0)
b=float(-2)
a/b
```

I get:

```
-0.0
```

Is there a way to get rid of this minus? The reason I want to this is because when I run the doctest and the expected value is 0.0 and I get -0.0 it says that test is failed, although it says `True` when I type `-0.0==0.0`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass the return value to [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs) to get its absolute value:

```
>>> a=float(0)
>>> b=float(-2)
>>> abs(a/b)
0.0
>>>
```